# How to install libgfortran.so.4 on Xubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: xubuntu, fortran

Calculix Crunchix FEA program does not run due to a missing library. the excutable was downloaded at http://www.dhondt.de/. Note that it was running on Xubuntu 20.04 LTS.

The error is:

```
ccx_2.20: error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I search on internet and some recommend to install **gfortran** which I did, but the error is the same.

In which package is this library ?

Comment: How did you obtain / install Calculix? AFAIK, Ubuntu 22.04 uses libgfortran.so.5 - so perhaps the software you are trying to use was built for a different version?

Comment: I edited the question to answer @steeldriver.

Comment: You can ask the packaging system which package (if any) provides `dpkg -S libgfortran.so.4`

Comment: @waltinator *dpkg-query* did not find no such package. Thanks.